# FetchError: invalid json response body while deploying the Nextjs application on a server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, github-actions

So I know this issue is duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580928/invalid-json-response-body-error-while-deploying-next-js-app-to-vercel) but in my case I have created my own API with Nextjs it gives results as expected in my deployment server. But as soon as I take it to production it fails.

[image]

Before that I wrote everything in getStaticProps() and it worked but when I created an API from it, its failing in production.
Here is the Github link for the [repository](https://github.com/VibhavSurve09/vibhavsurve)

Please help, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Fetch error when building Next.js static website in production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66206394/1870780)? You shouldn't call an internal API route in `getStaticProps`. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route.